# Thread safe way to copy ConcurrentQueue

Tags: c#, multithreading

Basically I want to achieve this:

```
private ConcurrentQueue<FormData> _formsData;

private void SaveForms()
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(_formsData.GetType());
    serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, _formsData);
}
```

But I assume it is not thread-safe to pass `ConcurrentQueue` as `object` parameter. So I need first to copy whole queue to another collection in a safe way, and then pass this new collection to `WriteObject`.

I found `CopyTo` method of `ConcurrentQueue`, which seems to be thread-safe. But it requires a pre-initialized array, so the code would be:

```
var data = new FormData[_formsData.Count];
_formsData.CopyTo(data, 0);
```

which again seems to be not safe (number of elements can be changed by other thread between `Count` and `CopyTo` call).

So is there a thread-safe way to copy `ConcurrentQueue`?

Comment: How about getting a `lock` on `_formsData`?

Comment: Then I would need to `lock` every usage of `_formsData`. And that completely breaks the idea of `ConcurrentQueue`. So I will use locks only if there is no other solution.

Comment: @Aleksey Shubin What about ToArray? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267275(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Brian thanks! For some reason I have missed it when looking through ConcurrentQueue methods.  If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Aleksey Shubin Happens to all of us. Glad it was that simple of an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ToArray method on ConcurrentQueue.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267275(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267275%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Is ToArray threadsafe? it does internally iterate through the items and create an array out of it.